# Why can't my phone connect to cell network data?

Tags: cyanogenmod, mobile-data, data-connection, cellular-radio

I have a Nexus 6P running CyanogenMod 13.0-20160819-SNAPSHOT-ZNH5YAO0IN-angler based on Android 6.0.1. I used to be running a CM nightly build and my cell carrier is Ting. Here's what happened:

I was running a CM nightly build from March-ish for a while. A couple days ago, I upgraded to the latest CM nightly. Immediately after that my WiFi stopped being able to find/connect to networks, and a day or so after the upgrade my cell network data connection stopped working. (SMS and phone calls worked, however.)

I decided to switch to a CyanogenMod snapshot release, so I factory reset the phone and flashed CM and gapps (at the same time). I wen through the setup and lo and behold, the problem appeared fixed. However, when I restored all my stuff via oandbackup (including, I now realize, some system apps), the problem reappeared.

Thinking that there was somehow some system app with corrupted data that I'd now restored, I used oandbackup again (along with a TWRP backup) and factory reset again. I went through the setup, planning to simply restore apps one by one until I found the culprit, but the freshly-setup install had the same problem. Therefore I restored the TWRP backup, which brings us to now.

So, why can't I connect to data? Most of the time this problem causes the cell indicator in the status bar to have a "!" however sometimes it shows just the bars, without a "!" or the "LTE" indicator. I *believe* this behavior occurs when the phone is first booted and goes away for the remainder of the boot when Airplane Mode is toggled, but I can't confirm for sure.

Here's what hasn't worked:

- Wiping Dalvik cache
- Trying most of the APNs, toggling Airplane Mode in-between
- Restoring the default APN settings
- Selecting a network operator (there used to be two or so "Ting" entries available; I only tried one - now nothing shows up at all)
- Selecting "choose automatically" in the Network operators settings
- Toggling the preferred network type to 3G and back to LTE (toggling to 3G caused everything but the status indicator bars [i.e. the "!" and "LTE"] to go to away; I suspect Ting simply doesn't have 3G available anymore)
- Turning on Data Roaming and toggling Airplane Mode
- Downloading a factory image from Google and running `flash-all.sh` (i.e. flashing stock recovery, system, radio, etc.)

ADB logs of me booting my phone to the launcher and waiting a couple seconds for it to connect to the cell network: https://gist.github.com/strugee/cd61dbcc461bb17216c360516e711d29

Comment: Probably a bad radio - nightlies are not stable versions, they have bugs. Did you read the release notes?

Comment: @esQmo I didn't read the release notes but as I said in the question, I'm not on a nightly anymore. I'm on a snapshot.

Comment: Flashing the nightly may have damaged the radio, or at least may have changed the radio. Try to flah a stock firmware and see if the problem is solved. You should read the release notes to know what is broken or not

Comment: @esQmo you mean the radio partition? or the physical radio?

Comment: The radio partition. I think the one you flashed with the nightly does not support your network or the 4G networks. A stock firmware could solve this.

Comment: @esQmo just flashed everything stock - radio, system, recovery, etc. no luck. I think I'll try contacting my carrier next.

Comment: Do you have correct APN settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this wasn't a problem with the phone. I called Ting customer support and apparently all that happened was I hit 5 GB of data usage, so they shut off my data automatically to prevent an unexpectedly huge bill at the end of the billing cycle.

According to the support person, you can self-service this by logging into Ting and looking at your device settings - the "can use data" option should be off. Turn it on and you'll be good to go.